# Bootstrap a grails app with dummy data when spring security facebook is involved

Tags: facebook, grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I've created a grails app that uses spring security to allow a user to authenticate via facebook, and I can successfully print out the facebook username onto one of the views, so thus far I don't have any issues.

My problem lies when trying to bootstrap my application with some sample data for my given facebook user, so I don't have to enter it every time the application starts up.

This is how I'm trying to bootstrap my own facebook account, I have the following in `Bootstrap.groovy` :

```
def adminRole = new AppRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
def userRole = new AppRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

def testUser = new AppUser(username: 'facebook_563645402', enabled: true,
                    password: 'my-hashed-pw-here',
            surveys: [jamies])
            testUser.save(flush: true)

AppUserAppRole.create testUser, adminRole, true
```

For the record, I've added a `hasMany` for the surveys field mentioned above onto AppUser.

When I fire up the app and try to connect, I get the following error :

```
URI
/web/j_spring_security_facebook_check
Class
grails.validation.ValidationException
Message
Validation Error(s) occurred during save(): - Field error in object 'web.AppUser' on field 'username': rejected value [facebook_563645402]; codes [web.AppUser.username.unique.error.web.AppUser.username,web.AppUser.username.unique.error.username,web.AppUser.username.unique.error.java.lang.String,web.AppUser.username.unique.error,appUser.username.unique.error.web.AppUser.username,appUser.username.unique.error.username,appUser.username.unique.error.java.lang.String,appUser.username.unique.error,web.AppUser.username.unique.web.AppUser.username,web.AppUser.username.unique.username,web.AppUser.username.unique.java.lang.String,web.AppUser.username.unique,appUser.username.unique.web.AppUser.username,appUser.username.unique.username,appUser.username.unique.java.lang.String,appUser.username.unique,unique.web.AppUser.username,unique.username,unique.java.lang.String,unique]; arguments [username,class web.AppUser,facebook_563645402]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] must be unique]
```

Which appears to complain about the username not being unique.

If by trying to bootstrap some data breaks the unique constraints on the facebook username, **how can I possibly ever pre define any data for a user**?

A quick Googling brings up a few suggestions ([link1](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/create-userroles-for-spring-security.html), [Grails spring security bootstrap](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/23%20Tutorials.html#23.1%20Using%20Controller%20Annotations%20to%20Secure%20URLs), but so far they haven't helped, any ideas?

**EDIT**:
Delving deeper into the error that grails reports, I can see that the root of the above error is located in `DefaultFacebookAuthDao`, line 135, which mentions the following :

```
AppUserDomainClazz.withTransaction {
                    appUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
                }
```

So, by authenticating, spring security attempts to save a user domain object...

**EDIT 2** :

This is my `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
def testUser = new AppUser(username: 'facebook_563645402', enabled: true,
                        password: 'my-hashed-pw', surveys: [new Survey(1)])
                testUser.save()

                def fbUser = new FacebookUser(uid: 563645402)
                fbUser.save(flush: true)
```

Both `FacebookUser` and `AppUser` were generated via the spring security facebook quickstart, with the only change being to add `static hasMany = [surveys: Survey]` to AppUser.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data has already been predefined, otherwise there wouldn't be a unique constraint violation. Just check for the existence of the data and only create it if needed:

```
def adminRole = AppRole.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
def userRole = AppRole.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_USER')

String username = 'facebook_563645402'

if (!AppUser.findByUsername(username)) {
   def testUser = new AppUser(username: username, enabled: true,
                              password: 'my-hashed-pw-here')
   testUser.addToSurveys(jamies)
   testUser.save()

   AppUserAppRole.create testUser, adminRole, true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Burt, but when I authenticate the user via facebook it still displays the unique constraint error. Looks like the bootstrap didn't encounter a problem, but more the login..does login attempt to create an additional AppUser therefore violate a unique constraint on username?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security Facebook tries to create a new user with same username (`facebook_563645402`). Because it cannot find it by `uid`.

As I see from you code, you just create an user, with filled `username`, but it's not a facebook user, and `uid` field isn't filled. So, the plugin cannot find any facebook user and tries to create a new one, using 'facebook_563645402' username by default.

There two ways: or change username for user created in Bootstrap (if it's not a facebook user), or create a Facebook User also (will be used for authentication).

Comment: Thanks Igor, but I believe your suggestion is not quite enough to solve this question, I have tried to create a FacebookUser but I still face the same constraint violation (see edit2 for what I have used in bootstrap)

Comment: try `def fbUser = new FacebookUser(uid: 563645402, user: testUser)`